# Extract text from captcha images using python

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

I want to read text from captcha images. Sample captcha image is in the above link.

Tried using pytesseract-ocr but did not identify overlapped characters

Comment: OCR based on Color?

Comment: images are color

Comment: Yes, so find the characters…